# Nginx + Passenger + GeoIP: Can't pass variable value to application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

So I'm installing a new server with Nginx v. 1.8, Rails 4.2 and Paasenger v. 5.0.21 and I'm trying to send GeoIP variables to the application this way:

```
passenger_env_var HTTP_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US;
passenger_env_var HTTP_GEOIP_VISITING_COUNTRY $geoip_country_code;
```

The first variable is correctly defined in the ENV hash in the application, but the second variable is set to "$geoip_country_code" instead of the country code detected by the GeoIP library.

I know that GeoIP is properly configured because I created a log_format and logged the value of the $geoip_country_code variable, with favorable results.

Does anybody know the right way to pass a Nginx variable as a Passenger Env Var?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered on Github: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1664